# Not allowed to exceed free API quota for Time Zone API on GCP

Tags: api, google-maps, google-api, google-cloud-platform

I have an issue in my project where the Time Zone API won’t let me increase beyond the free quota. Billing is enabled for this project, but it won’t let me increase beyond 2500 req/day.

According to the [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/usage-limits), since billing is enabled I should be able to increase my limit to 100k/day.

I have several other projects running that will let me increase up to 100k/day. I just created a new project a few minutes ago, and sure enough, after enabling billing, I’m able to increase to 100k/day
It seems broken only on my one project. I’ve disabled/enabled it, etc. to no avail.
I started using an API key from another project just to get around it, but billing just got disabled for that project, so I’m back to having issues again.
I’ve tried leaving feedback via the cloud console and asking in a couple other places. But I’m being told that the places I’m asking in aren’t the right places, and leaving feedback multiple times has yielded no results after about a month.
I’m kind of at a loss now on where to go. Any suggestions on how to get this working would be very welcome at this point.

This is what I see in my project (with billing enabled).
[image]

This is what I SHOULD see in my project.
[image: Time Zone API quota limited to 100,000 req/day]

Comment: Also check your daily budget (in the App Engine -> Settings), there were reports of paid features not working until the daily budget was initialized.

Comment: Budgets are fine. They're set fairly high because we're getting a good amount of traffic on this app now. So, we've got plenty of margin.

Comment: Is the issue resolved yet for you?

Comment: After several emails back and forth with GCP billing support, they were able to resolve this a couple days ago.

Comment: Great to know it was fixed for you! Such occurrences (behavior doesn't match documentation) can be reported through the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/) as well.